# how to use kill command only with files name without PID

Tags: linux, bash, grep, kill

I wanna kill programs with one command

```
ps -elf | grep "common_program_name" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

but I got an error

```
kill: failed to parse argument: 'S
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why did yo use `awk '{print $2}'`? With your `ps` the process id is in the 4th column, it works with $4.

Comment: yes it works, thank you so much ! @Oleg

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww The lines above are written in Bash, or perhaps even its subset of Borne Shell.  Believe it or not, some people program in Bash, and thus, code like the line above is considered a program to some.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, there is nothing bash-specific about the pipeline in the question. Pipes work in sh, csh, fish, etc., and the programs in use here are all external to the shell. But that aside, this is an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). It asks for help implementing a solution, not in solving the underlying problem.

Comment: Technically only the vbars. The rest are external programs.

Comment: @EdwinBuck - I believe the bar is higher than adding "... in a script" to a question. If the problem is reduced to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which it appears so), then it is just a question on how to run commands. There are better sites to ask those types of questions.

Comment: @jww On some days, the bar is higher.  On some days it isn't.  But, StackOverflow is getting to be really picky.  Almost too picky.  We used to allow people to ask bigger questions.  We used to allow people to ask for guidance learning things.  We used to permit a lot of bad questions too.  Perhaps we threw out some of the good with the bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use `killall -9 common_program_name`

the problem above is that you might have more than one instance of the program running.

Also, you are fetching the second column from the output of `ps` That column does not contain a PID, so your `xargs` command effectively runs `kill -9 S`  Perhaps you can adjust your flags to `ps` or your field captured by `awk` to make the above work, but there are already purpose built programs which do this job.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pkill`, in your case `pkill -9 common_program_name` (for more see `man pkill`) which gives you the functionality you're looking for. And unlike `killall` won't kill literally all process on System V UNIX machines. ;)